# How do I access camera using python?

Tags: python, opencv

When I run the code to access camera the live feed comes for a second and then it gives an error.

Here is the code:

```
import cv2,time
video=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
check,frame=video.read()

print(check)
print(frame)
cv2.imshow("capturing", frame)
cv2.waitkey(1)
video.release()
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/1 Files and Folders/SHARAN/code/My Projects/os.py", line 8, in <module>
    cv2.waitkey(1)
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'waitkey'
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-cff9bdsm\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (435) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

Comment: `waitKey`  not waitkey

Answer (score 1):

`waitKey` is the correct code.
you should change k to capital letter

```
import cv2,time

video=cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
check,frame=video.read()

print(check) 
print(frame) 
cv2.imshow("capturing", frame) 
cv2.waitKey(1) #you should change this

video.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem, is that you typed `waitkey` rather than `waitKey`.
The second problem, you aren't using a main loop for your frames, resulting in only one frame to be captured.

You can fix both of those with the following added:

```py
import cv2, time

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True: # Place this in an infinite loop (to make it live)

  check, frame = video.read()

  print(check)
  print(frame)

  cv2.imshow("capturing", frame)

  if cv2.waitKey(1): # Change it to waitKey instead

    break

video.release()
```

If you only wanted one frame, then by all means disregard my suggestion. :)